# passing an element from one UIWebView to another

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, uiwebview

I am making an app that uses two UIWebViews. On one of them i strip the webpage for javascript and load it (to make the page appear faster). The other one loads the full page with javascript in the background and replaces the other UIWebView when it's done. The page with javascript will have some added banners and stuff making it bigger.

Im trying to make the UIWebView automatically scroll to the same place (element) where the user were on the other WebView. Ive been trying to do this through javascript (using document.elementFromPoint), but i cant find a way to pass an Element to the other UIWebView (dont know if its even possible). I can't locate the element through Id either becuase they dont have Id atributes.

Is there a way to pass an element as a variable from one UIWebView to another? or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Do you have any ideas why the page loads slowly with JavaScript? what kinds of DOM modifications do you do? when do you do them, dom ready? if you want the render fast a tip is to provide sizes (width and height attributes) to as many elements as possible to make the layout engine happy.

Comment: If you want hints on what takes time i suggest that you load the page in chrome and use the profiler, timeline and audits tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script` for passing parameters.

The javascript method can return the string which is then returned by the above method. It can return the data in form of JSON for multiple values which you can parse then using JSON parser. Or it can simply return a string. You can use that string/JSON-data further.

To pass the value see following code :

```
NSString *jsPrintBodyOfTable=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@”printBodyOfTable((\”%@\”))”, content.at_content];

 [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsPrintHeadOfTable];
```

Simple tutorial at  http://howtomakeitinamsterdam.wordpress.com/2011/12/17/uiwebview-calling-javascript-from-ios-with-passing-parameters-tutorial/

Comment: My problem is finding the same element one the other UIWebView that i found in the first one. Say the element i look for looks something like this: <p> bla bla bla </p>. Would it be possible to pass that entire element out as a string and then locating it again using that string?

Comment: Yes I think you can return "<p> bla bla bla </p>". Then you can pass this string on to your javascript method which can locate it in the webview. Have you tried it?

Comment: Thats what im trying to find out how to do. I know how to locate the element and i think i will be able to search for it when i have it, but i dont know how to get it returned as a string.

Comment: NSString *str = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"javaScriptMethod"]; javaScriptMethod should return the desired String. Then pass this str variable to your second javascript method which can locate it in the webview.   Did you try like this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to plainly pass it from one UIWebView to another.

However, if you define a protocol of your own and pass your data as a URL, you can pass data to the native environment, then you can extract and execute Javascript on the other web view to inject the data.

Catching the URL can be done with `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` in a class that implements UIWebViewDelegate protocol, and execute Javascript can be done with `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` on the UIWebView instance.

This is what is done in PhoneGap/Cordova, if you look at the source code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a DOM property which is what your are looking for: `scrollY`, so you can retrieve it in your first web view:

```
NSString* scrollPosition = [webView1 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"scrollY"];
```

and then make the second scroll to it:

```
[webView2 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
     [NSString stringWithFormat: @"window.scrollTo(0, %d);", scrollPosition]];
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the two pages are of different height.